# How to pass arguments in a custom blade directive?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1

In Laravel 5.1, I am trying to create a very basic blade directive:

```
Blade::directive('hello', function ($planet) {
    return 'Hello ' . $planet;
});
```

When I write:

```
@hello('world')
```

It returns:

```
Hello ('world')
```

I want:

```
Hello world
```

Yes I can remove these brackets manually but is it a bug in Laravel or what? How can I get `world` instead of `(world)` as the value of `$planet`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
Blade::directive('hello', function ($planet) {
    return "<?php echo 'Hello' . $planet ?>";
});

@hello('world'); // => Hello world
```

You can also pass an **array** instead of string, in that case you have to define how the array should be handled in the return value, here's an example:

```
Blade::directive('hello', function ($value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
       return "<?php echo 'Hello' . $value[0] . ' and ' . $value[1] ?>";
    }

    if (is_string($planets)) {
       return "<?php echo 'Hello' . $value ?>";
    }

    // fallback when value is not recognised
    return "<?php echo 'Hello' ?>";
});

@hello('world'); // => Hello world
@hello(['world', 'mars']); // => Hello world mars
```

Comment: @HomoSapien -- this method returns php code, but your method returns string

Comment: Can you pass Array as argument? Looks like it is every time converted into a string.

Comment: Yea, I could not pass more than one param.. any idea?

Comment: Does that even work? I tried it and always the $value is string